# Difficulties opening PDFs in Preview

Tags: preview

When I am working with 10 – 15 open windows in Preview I often accounter the problem that I can't open a new PDF-window. Instead I need to open it in iBooks to make it work. I have no other PDF viewers installed.

Has anyone else had this problem and does any one know what I can do about it?

Comment: How many is "several" (5 or 500)? And are you sure that you can't open a new window or may the new window be hidden behind others?

Comment: You hit spacebar to open them?

Comment: By several I mean about 10-15. When a try to open the PDF (double click) I can see the initial animation that a new window is about to open but it then nothing more happens. It is not possible to see the new PDF-window in the all-open-windows directory.

Comment: Are we talking about Open all files in one widow or separate windows

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I mean that I look both at the Mission control and also holding thePreview icon to see what files are open.

Comment: Could it be that your system is running out of RAM? How much RAM do you have? When you encounter this problem with Preview, do you also have a lot of other applications open and running and displaying other documents? How about pages in Safari or another web browser? The more you have going on, the less RAM your system has to work with. Do you go for days at a time without restarting your Mac? This affects available RAM as well.

Comment: I'm running a Mac Book Air with 4 GB RAM and although the RAM sometimes runs out when running heavy programs this is not the case when the above problem happens. But it might be a memory issue. This usually happens when I have at least one open document in full screen mode and if I restart Preview I am able to open the file again. However it does not work if i close all open windows still running the program.

Comment: Preview has a setting to open all selected files in one widow, or open each in a separate window, which one is it.

Comment: Thank you @Buscar웃. I noticed the setting had changed to "Open groups of files in the same window" so this could be the reason. I have now chosen "Open each file in new window" and I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Seb, what do you call “the all-open-windows directory” ?

Comment: I mean the shortcut that shows all open windows of a running program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview has 2 settings for opening files.

One is Open all files in same window

the Second one is Open all files in separate window.

The open all files in one window side bar will show all files, and will add a new open file toit.

But, check your settings for Sort by in the side bar, pending those setting the new file might not open at the bottom of the list, so with 15 files open you might miss it.