# Preview: Opening more than 12 pdf files in new windows

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I've noticed that whenever I have **12** or more pdf files open at one time (each in a separate window) and attempt to open an *additional* pdf, this additional pdf opens in the *same window* as the pdf on top. In other words, it's as if the "Open each file in its own window" is disabled once I reach **12** open pdfs.

I can then *transfer* the newly-opened pdf to a new window by right-clicking on the pdf's thumbnail and selecting "Open in New Window" but I don't want to have to do that every time I want to open an additional file. Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

Again, I already have the "Open each file in its own window" option enabled (and it works when I have less 12 pdfs already opened).

Lastly, assuming this is deliberate on Apple's part (i.e. not some sort of bug), is there a reason why I should be wary of opening up more than 12 pdfs in separate windows? And what other options are there for opening up pdfs in OS X other than via Preview? (I'm sure there are plenty of third-party apps available but I'm particularly interested in built-in alternatives).

Thanks.

[Note: A similar issue was mentioned here:
[Difficulties opening PDFs in Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130600/difficulties-opening-pdfs-in-preview) but the solution offered doesn't apply.]

OS X - Macbook Pro;
Version 10.9.3

[EDIT: This behavior has occurred periodically for a while now (months)--it seems to occur *after* I've opened files in Preview that have been *saved as PDFs* via the "Save as PDF" option from the "Print" window.]

Comment: I do not have this behaviour on 10.9.3. Which implies the issue is local and not a deliberate behaviour.   Please add what Mac version and Operating version you are using.

Comment: How did you test to see if you had this behavior?

Comment: I opened 12 pdfs from a folder. Once each opened in it's own window I opened some more by double clicking them. I also just test from the Web Receipts folder, same result

Answer (score -2):

You can use [the mastodont *Adobe Reader*](http://get.adobe.com/reader/).

In fact, this app from Adobe, formerly named Acrobat, was the app provided in Macs, before Preview existed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, not even attempts to.